# Discord.py — UserNotFound error after attempting to ban user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I'm trying to design a Discord bot that can ban a user across two different servers of mine if I ban them on the main server. When testing the progress so far, everything seemed to work until it came to actually banning the user. No errors came up, but the user wasn't banned. When I try to test again, I keep getting UserNotFound errors. I've restarted the bot, re-added it and the test subject user to both servers, and tried to clear the cache, but the bot still doesn't seem to recognize the user exists anymore.

This is the code for the ban command:

```
async def totalban(ctx, userID):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator: # check if admin
        if ctx.guild.id == GUILD_ID: # if admin, check if right guild
            await ctx.send('Confirmed administrator on proper server.')
            time.sleep(1)
            global TARGET_ID
            TARGET_ID = int(userID) # record target user ID
            converter = UserConverter()
            user = await converter.convert(ctx, userID) # convert arg to User
            username = user.name + '#' + user.discriminator # easy reference in Name#1234 format
            global TARGET_USERNAME
            TARGET_USERNAME = username
            await ctx.send('User ID ' + userID + ' corresponds to ' + username + '.')
            time.sleep(1)
            await ctx.send('To confirm ban of ' + username + ', type **!confirmtotalban ' + username + '** now.')
            global CANCONFIRMBAN
            CANCONFIRMBAN = True # allow !confirmtotalban command to function
        else:
            await ctx.send('Cannot run command from this server.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('User unauthorized to run command.')
```

And this is is the function I ran when trying to ban the test account:

(If it's any help, I never had UserNotFound errors before running this code.)

```
async def banloop(ctx):
    global TARGET_ID
    for guild in ctx.bot.guilds:
        await guild.ban(TARGET_ID)
```

And here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...\example_bot.py", line 41, in totalban
    user = await converter.convert(ctx, userID) # convert arg to User
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 194, in convert
    raise UserNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.UserNotFound: User "165995850303012864" not found.
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer, and let me know if you need any more information out of me.

Comment: I havnt looked at your code in detail but have you made sure the bot has permissions to ban them cause that troubled me for half a week

Comment: Yes, the bot was added to both servers with ban privileges.

Comment: Is the rank of this player higher then the bot's in server roles, another issue i encountered

Comment: No, I think they're the same, actually.

Comment: The use of global variables may be part of the problem, as global variables have  a tendency to make code really hard to debug.  Is this the only location where TARGET_ID is modified?

Comment: It's initiated as 0 at the top of the program, but other than that, this is the only modification.

Comment: It's not a good idea to make a separate confirmation command with the same variables because you can end up with a race condition where two admins execute the command, and the confirmation bans only the second user. Try using `wait_for` to get a reaction confirmer or something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
 TARGET_ID = int(userID) # record target user ID
```

If I understand it right, you convert userID to integer here. However,

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.UserNotFound: User "165995850303012864" not found.
```

Target ID shows up as a string on the error. You may want to check it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the issue. The program evidently recognizes any other users, but just not the one I'd originally tried to ban.

Comment: Have you tried taking a Discord.member as an argument and try to execute your ban command that way?

Answer (score 0):

The error in the traceback is complaining about the `UserConverter.convert()` call in your `totalban()` function which produces the `UserNotFound` error.  Because this function call causes the error, it means that `CANCONFIRMBAN` will never be set to true which would explain why no one ends up getting banned.

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=userconverter#discord.ext.commands.UserConverter), `UserConverter.convert()` accepts a string argument.  Are you certain that the `userID` argument in `totalban()` is a string and not an integer value?

There is also this note on how the `UserConverter` is able to convert values to a User object:

> All lookups are via the global user cache.

- Are you sure that the internal cache of the bot is ready?
- Is `fetch_offline_members` set to False?  This greatly limits the functionality of bots and can make it impossible to do many things.
- Have you tried calling the function with `name#discrim` instead of the user ID?

It is difficult to help solve the problem with certainty without more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. How would you suggest checking to see if the internal cache is ready?

Comment: @yellowlightgreen Try calling ctx.bot.is_ready() and print it before you convert.

Comment: Also, consider trying to make your friend have slightly lower privileges than the bot and check if that makes the error go away.